# Adding a column to a tibble using string matching

Tags: r

I am trying to add a new column into a data frame by matching words from a different column. To use mtcars as an example, I want to create a column "country" by scanning each rowname for a string. To go through the first few rows in pseudocode:

```
if "Mazda" in rowname then "Japan"
if "Datsun" in rowname then "Japan"
if "Hornet" in rowname then "USA"
etc
```

I've tried using mutate with the map function, but to no avail.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: All of these were very helpful. With the data I'm working with, using case_when() was the easiest/quickest, but I could have used any of these answers. Thanks a ton for all who responded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `case_when()` or `ifelse()`:

```
library(dplyr)

mt <- head(mtcars, 5)

mt %>% 
  mutate(new_col = case_when(
    mpg == 21.0 ~ "new",
    TRUE ~ "A"
  ))
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb new_col
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     new
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     new
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1       A
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1       A
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2       A
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple `if/else` or nested `ifelse`, we can have a key/val dataset and join with the original data

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr
library(stringr)
keyvaldat <- tibble(make = c("Mazda", "Datsun", "Hornet"),
                     Country = c("Japan", "Japan", "USA"))     

rownames_to_column(mtcars, "rn") %>%
       mutate(make = word(rn, 1)) %>%
       left_join(keyvaldat) %>%
       head(4)
#            rn  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   make Country
#1      Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  Mazda   Japan
#2  Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  Mazda   Japan
#3     Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 Datsun   Japan
#4 Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 Hornet     USA
```

NOTE: If there are 100- values to change, then it would be 100 `ifelse` statements. Better would be a join

Answer (score 0):

Use a named vector (`x` in this example)

```
library(dplyr)
x = c(Mazda = "Japan", Datsun = "Japan", Hornet = "USA")
mtcars %>%
    mutate(Make = row.names(.)) %>%
    select(Make) %>%
    mutate(Country = x[sapply(strsplit(Make, " "), function(x) x[1])])
```